# .htaccess - www to non-www & http to https & include trailing slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need help with my .htaccess file. I want to have a 301 redirect from HTTP to HTTPS and from www to non-www with a trailing slash at the end. I can't remove trailing slash from posts because WordPress adds it at the end of the URL and when I remove it all my posts return a 404 error and some plugins don't work.

I ended with results like:

- http://www.example.com/post -> **https://example.com/post** -> https://example.com/post/
- http://example.com/index.php -> **https://example.com/index.php** -> https://example.com/

I'm new on this forum so I can't add more than 8 links so I made a screenshot with more details.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLDqD.png)

Current .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Is there any way to get rid of the bolded part to have only one 301 redirects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add a trailing slash with www removal and https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule [^/]$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,NE,R=301]

# handle www->non www, http->https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: It works a way better, than my version. Thank you :)
Still, there is a small chain of 301 redirects but I think that it has to be there:
https://www.example.com/index.php
301 Moved Permanently
https://example.com/index.php
301 Moved Permanently
https://example.com/
200 OK